# Show information on web-page from external process in n2o framework

Tags: erlang, n2o

How can I show information from external processes in N2O framefork.

Code like this:

```
tokyoWeather() ->
     timer:sleep(10000),
     Data = getTokyoWeater(),
     ??? SHOW_ON_PAGES,
     tokyoWeather().
lisbonWeather() ->
     timer:sleep(10000),
     Data = getLisbonWeater(),
     ??? SHOW_ON_PAGES,
     lisbonWeather().
```

Page1:

```
body() ->
    [ #panel { id=TokyoWeather text= <<>> },
      #panel { id=LisbonWeather, text= <<>> },
      ...].
```

Page2:

```
body() ->
    [ #panel { id=TokyoWeather text= <<>> },
      #panel { id=LisbonWeather, text= <<>> },
      ...].
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use **wf:reg** and **wf:flush** functions. Example: [/samples/apps/review/src/index.erl](https://github.com/5HT/n2o/blob/2.1/samples/apps/review/src/index.erl#L44)

1. Register unique name for a page-process:

   **23:** `event(init) -> wf:reg(room)...`
2. Updating DOM:

   **60:** `wf:insert_bottom(history, Terms)`
3. Flushing changes to browser using page-process name:

   **62:** `wf:flush(room)`

Answer (score 1):

Documentation suggests using **wf:reg/1** and **wf:flush**. However, this requires you to register process into a pool, which is handy for when you want to manipulate multiple processes at once, but quite redundant otherwise.

Another interesting function the N2O book mentions is **wf:flush/1**. Its description claims that it does something completely different from **wf:flush/0**, while in reality it does not. It really just collects the wf actions placed into a "buffer" and sends them via **wf:send/2** to a registered supposedly websocket processes. Meanwhile the websocket process sits in a timed **receive** loop.

After some N2O's code inspection, there is a pretty simple solution, in my opinion:

1. Starting at process that can render actions(e.g. the websocket process), spawn your desired function and pass the parent process id as one of its parameters

   ```
   async_render() ->
     Pid = self(),
     spawn(fun() -> update(Pid) end).
   ```
2. Perform your **wf** actions in now asynchronous function, then retrieve the queued actions, clear the buffer, and finally send the a tuple of `{flush, Actions}` to your parent process.

   ```
   update(Pid) ->
     %% Your wf:insert..., update, etc. code here
     Actions = wf:actions(),
     wf:actions([]),
     Pid ! {flush, Actions}.
   ```

The rest is done by N2O for you :)